# Apply ActionFilterAttribute to the entire WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I've setup a custom ActionFilterAttribute for my WebAPI

Is there a way to apply this to all WebAPI controllers at once, versus adding the [ActionFilter] to every single WebAPI controller?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982049/mvc-4-web-api-register-filter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add your action filter attribute to global filters which applies to all API controllers from WebApiConfig class's Register method.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
          public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
          {
                 // Web API configuration and services
                    config.Filters.Add(new TestFilterAttribute());
          }
}
```