# Custom Authorization in Asp.net WebApi - what a mess?

Tags: asp.net, authorization, asp.net-web-api

*I'm reading from several resources  (books and SO answers) about  authorization in WebApi.*

Suppose I want to add Custom Attribute  which allows access only for Certain Users:

**Case #1**

I've seen this approach of  *overriding*  `OnAuthorization` , which sets response if something is wrong

```
public class AllowOnlyCertainUsers : AuthorizeAttribute
{
 public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
   if ( /*check if user OK or not*/)
   {
     actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
   }
  }
}
```

**Case #2**

But I've also seen this similar example which also  overriding  `OnAuthorization` but with calling to `base` :

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) 
{ 
  base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

    // If not authorized at all, don't bother

    if (actionContext.Response == null)  
     {
      //...
     }
}
```

*Then, you check if the
`HttpActionContext.Response` is set or not. If it’s not set, it means that the request is authorized and the user is ok*

**Case #3**

But I've also seen this approach of overriding `IsAuthorized`  :

```
public class AllowOnlyCertainUsers : AuthorizeAttribute
{
 protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext context)
  {
   if ( /*check if user OK or not*/)
   {
    return true;// or false
   }
  }
}
```

**Case #4**

And then I saw similar example one but with calling base.IsAuthorized(context) :

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext context)
{
 if (something1 && something2 && base.IsAuthorized(context)) //??
 return true;
 return false;
}
```

*One more thing*

And finally Dominick said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148050/custom-authorizations-in-web-api#comment-21417166)  :

*You shouldn't override OnAuthorization - because you would be missing [AllowAnonymous] handling.*

**Questions**

- 1) Which methods should I use : `IsAuthorized` or `OnAuthorization` ? ( or when to use which)
- 2) when should I call `base.IsAuthorized or` base.OnAuthorization` ?
- 3) Is this how they built it ? that if the response is null then everything is ok ? ( case #2)

NB

Please notice , I'm using ( and want to use ) only `AuthorizeAttribute` which already inherits from  `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`

Why ?

Becuase I'm at the first stage in : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

[image]

Anyway Im asking via extending Authorize attribute .

Comment: What you need to override the Authorize attribute? What is the usecase you want to achieve? If you need to allow access for certain users why not to use [Authorize(Users="Admin")] attribute like this?

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh For example Try to authorrize users between 10:00 to 12:00 (configureable). you cant do that with plain Roles and authorized attr. you have to make your own logic

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> Which methods should I use : IsAuthorized or OnAuthorization ? ( or
>   when to use which)

You will extend `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` if your authorization logic is not dependent on the identity established and roles. For user related authorization, you will extend and use `AuthorizeAttribute`. For the former case, you will override `OnAuthorization`. For the latter case, you will override `IsAuthorized`. As you could see from the source code of these attributes, `OnAuthorization` is marked virtual for you to override if you derive from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. On the other hand, the `IsAuthorized` method is marked virtual in `AuthorizeAttribute`. I believe this is a good pointer to the intended usage.

> when should I call base.IsAuthorized or base.OnAuthorization?

The answer to this question lies in how OO generally works. If you override a method, you can either completely provide a new implementation or piggy back on the implementation provided by parent and enhance the behavior. For example, take the case of `IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext)`. The base class behavior is to check the user/role against what is specified in the filter vs the  identity established. Say, you want to do all that but in addition, you want to check something else, may be based on a request header or something. In that case, you can provide an override like this.

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    bool isAuthroized = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    // Here you look at the header and do your additional stuff based on actionContext
    // and store the result in isRequestHeaderOk
    // Then, you can combine the results
    // return isAuthorized && isRequestHeaderOk;
}
```

I'm sorry but don't understand your Q3. BTW, Authorization filter has been around for a long time and people use it for all kinds of things and sometimes incorrectly as well.

> One more thing. And finally there was this guy here who said : You
>   shouldn't override OnAuthorization - because you would be missing
>   [AllowAnonymous] handling.

The guy who said that is the God of access control - Dominick. Obviously it will be correct. If you look at the implementation of `OnAuthorization` (copied below),

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
    }

    if (SkipAuthorization(actionContext))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!IsAuthorized(actionContext))
    {
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
}
```

the call to `SkipAuthorization` is the part that ensures `AllowAnonymous` filters are applied, that is, authorization is skipped. If you override this method, you loose that behavior. Actually, if you decide to base your authorization on users/roles, at that point you would have decided to derive from `AuthorizeAttribute`. Only correct option left for you at that point will be to override `IsAuthorized` and not the already overridden `OnAuthorization`, although it is technically possible to do either.

PS. In ASP.NET Web API, there is another filter called authentication filter. Idea is that you use that for authentication and authorization filter for authorization, as the name indicates. However, there are lots of examples where this boundary is fudged. Lots of authroization filter examples will do some kind of authentication. Anyways, if you have time and want to understand a bit more, take a look at this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx). Disclaimer: It was written by me.

Comment: Thanks again , but if I read between the lines , IsAuthenticated is calles by OnAuthirization , so why  not override OnAuthorization and call base.OnAuthorization and then check response ?

Comment: You sure can, if that is what you want.

Comment: In my third question I meant : after running base function - base.OnAuthorization for example , does the only way to check if it was successful- is to inspect the Response property?, ps the examples are from your book :-)

Comment: Yes, typically you look for 401 status code but not null, as far as I know. BTW, I don't remember writing about overriding `OnAuthorization` in my book. I'm sure I'd not have written about checking response for null, coz this is the first time I'm hearing about it:)

Comment: Yes   I got confused with the other book. I'm reading 3 books simultaneously : securty(yours) , practical(yours) and webapi pro(Tugberk's, Zeitler,Ali). AS you can see - they did it there :  http://i.stack.imgur.com/LNGi4.jpg - they just checked if null , so should i check null or error codes ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about what the intention is, with the custom attribute you have shown. If the idea is to just check for a user in one or more roles, you could just use `[Authorize(Roles="Affiliate")]` without any sub-classing.

Comment: Badri first of all thank you for sharing knowledge and correcting me . Yes i know , but my intention is to know perfectly this custom authorization.  Did you see the image in my last comment ? They check if Response is null , but you told me to look if error headers exists . So which way should i go ?

Comment: Hey, I meant I'm not sure about the intention of null checking response in the custom filter in the book. I took a look at the code you have shown and response is null all the time.

Comment: Badri Hi , [I found it in your book](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x83HI.jpg) :  Why setting the `context.Response` is ending the request ? don't get me wrong , it is , but where is it written ? (docs , code, something ...) ps it relates to my third question ( checking `if (actionContext.Response == null)...`) I also saw it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17317849/859154) - it seems that setting Response, stops ecerything and spit out the response. can you please shed light ?

Comment: Badri can you please answer my last comment ?

Comment: Please look at the source code of `ActionFilterAttribute`. https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/ActionFilterAttribute.cs. The `ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore` method checks `actionContext.Response != null` and returns the response thus short-circuiting the pipeline. Only when response is null, it awaits continuation. The best way to understand a framework is to look at the source code. Since frameworks like ASP.NET MVC, Web API (ASP.NET vNext too) are open-source, we are fortunate.

Comment: You couldn't answer it in a better way. At first sight it was a bit dirty because the thing itself is confusing, but now it's seems to be pretty clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you guys check my post here, having trouble implementing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422043/webapi-custom-authorize-attribute-not-working

Comment: Hi, you mentioned that `base.isAuthorized` checks the user against the "filter", what is this filter and how do I specify it?

Answer (score 18):

Ok, my suggestion is to do the following assuming that you are using OAuth bearer tokens to protect your Web API and you are setting the allowedTime as a claim for the user when you issued the token. You can read more about [token based authentication here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

1. Create CustomAuthorizeAttribute which derives from AuthorizationFilterAttribute
2. override method `OnAuthorizationAsync` and use the sample code below:

   ```
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
   {

       public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {

           var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

           if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
           }

           var userName = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
           var userAllowedTime = principal.FindFirst("userAllowedTime").Value;

           if (currentTime != userAllowedTime)
           {
               actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Not allowed to access...bla bla");
               return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
           }

           //User is Authorized, complete execution
           return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

       }
   }
   ```
3. Now in your controllers you use CustomAuthorize attribute to protect your controllers using this authorization logic.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm currently using `AuthorizeAttribute` which does inherit `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` and -also for learning I specifically asked about which method should I use and about the Response has content or not thingy...

Answer (score 5):

[ASP.NET v5 Introduced a completely new Authorization System.](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/introduction.html) 
For those who are going to Use .NET 5 i would suggest moving into Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.

Pretty much it wraps up the mess caused by keeping both 
`System.Web.Http.Authorize` and `System.Web.Mvc.Authorize` and other older authentication implementations.

It provides a very good abstraction of Action Types(Create, Read, Update, Delete), Resources, Roles, Claims, Views, Custom Requirements and allows to build custom Handlers, combining any of the above.
In addition those handlers can be used in combination also.

> In ASP.NET v5 authorization now provides simple declarative role and a
>   richer policy based model where authorization is expressed in
>   requirements and handlers evaluate a users claims against
>   requirements. Imperative checks can be based on simple policies or
>   polices which evaluate both the user identity and properties of the
>   resource that the user is attempting to access.

Comment: Good to know, but does not answer the question at all.