# WebApi's OnAuthorizarion - Clarification?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Looking at a *custom* `AuthorizeAttribute` , I already know that the right method for checking authorization is the `IsAuthorized` method :

*For example :*

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    bool isAuthroized = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    return isAuthroized  && MY_OTHER_CONDITIONs; //!
}
```

*Like I said I already know that.*

But let's say I've decided to override `OnAuthorization` :

[**Here is an example** code from an existing library:](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AdvancedWebAPI/blob/master/PerRouteMHOwnershipSample/Filters/CustomerOrdersAuthorizeAttribute.cs#L23)

```
public class CustomerOrdersAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) 
      {

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        // If not authorized at all, don't bother checking for the 
        // customer - order relation
        if (actionContext.Response == null) 
          {
             //Get customer key  
             int customerKey = GetCustomerKey(actionContext.Request.GetRouteData());

             //Check customer-order relation
            if (!customer.Name.Equals(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)) 
             {
               actionContext.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
             }
           }
       }
  }
```

**Question:**

Looking at the author's code :  `if (actionContext.Response == null) {...}` and his comment : "*If not authorized at all*"

— Is this the **right**  way for checking if an exception has not  occurred in the `OnAuthorization` method ? Checking for `Response == null ?` (*which means : no exception output from  the `base.OnAuthorization`*) ?

*(Seems strange to me , because an exception can occur and still response to be null.....or am I wrong ? Also - the last thing I want to do is to start investigate headers codes for errors...)*

NB

My question is targeting WebApi1 not 2.x

Comment: Already got an answer. can't delete it.

Comment: If you have an answer just post it!

Comment: Read Badri's last comment in his answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464848/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-webapi-what-a-mess/26470711#comment-41740634

Comment: in other words : http://i.stack.imgur.com/dNLyL.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here :

Read Badri's last comment in his answer

[Custom Authorization in Asp.net WebApi - what a mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464848/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-webapi-what-a-mess/26470711#comment-41740634)

also here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNLyL.jpg