# Asp.Net Web Api 2 entry point to validate licence - Portable.Licensing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, licensing

I'm developing a Asp.Net Web Api 2 application. And I have an developed a licencing module based on [portable.licensing](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing) to validate weather the application  has a valid licence installed.

**Questions**

1. What is the entry point to validate the licence?
2. What is the entry point to for a Asp.Net Area, to validate the licence for specific area?

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage of the Authorize attribute.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: also see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464848/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-webapi-what-a-mess