# .NET Core API Conditional Authentication attributes for Development & Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, angular, asp.net-core

Long story short, Is it possible to place an environment based authorization attribute on my API so that the authorization restriction would be turned off in development and turned back on in Production?

I have a separate Angular 2 project that I wish to call a .NET Core API with.  We created a separate project so we could open the Angular 2 project in vscode and debug the typescript.  When we are finished, we will build the project and place it inside the .NET Core project for security reasons.

Our problem is that during the debugging stages, we are unable to connect to the API because they are two separate projects and our Angular 2 project does not have Active Directory.  The .NET Core project currently has Authentication Attributes and wont allow access (401) to the API.  It would be nice if we could turn that off during development and back on during production.

I'm also open to any other suggestions on how we can best solve this problem.

```
[Authorize: (Only in Production)] <-- // something like this???
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    ...
```

Comment: why not create your own custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that only override the `IsAuthorized`? There's [plenty examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26470711/28004)  on how to do that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

ASP.NET Core authorization is based on policies. As you may have seen, the `AuthorizeAttribute` can take a policy name so it knows which criteria need to be satisfied for the request to be authorized. I suggest that you have a read of the [great documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) on that subject.

Back to your problem, it looks like you don't use a specific policy, so it uses the default one, which [requires the user to be authenticated](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/fa64b0c0fb193c584d5d0835293860f92469145a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationOptions.cs#L28) by default.

You can change that behaviour in `Startup.cs`. If you're in development mode, you can redefine the default policy so that it doesn't have any requirements:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(x =>
    {
        // _env is of type IHostingEnvironment, which you can inject in
        // the ctor of Startup
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            x.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().Build();
        }
    });
}
```

---

#### Update

im1dermike mentioned in a comment that an `AuthorizationPolicy` needs at least one requirement, as we can see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/2d7cd6038fea34b84084685648ac9d0c97be610b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationPolicy.cs#L40). That code wasn't introduced recently, so it means the solution above was broken the whole time.

To work around this, we can still leverage the [`RequireAssertion`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/2d7cd6038fea34b84084685648ac9d0c97be610b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.cs#L211) method of `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` and add a dummy requirement. This would look like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(x =>
    {
        // _env is of type IHostingEnvironment, which you can inject in
        // the ctor of Startup
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            x.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAssertion(_ => true)
                .Build();
        }
    });
}
```

This ensures we have at least one requirement in the authorization policy, and we know that it will always pass.

Comment: When I implemented this in my .NETCoreApp 1.1, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'AuthorizationPolicy must have at least one requirement.'` error.

Comment: Is there any chance to fake/inject a signed-in user for development?

Comment: Will this apply to all usages of [Authorize]? If you'd like to pick where this applies, you would need to go with Woot's answer?

Comment: This process doesn't work in Core 2.0 since there is no DefaultPolicy object.  Does someone have a solution for this in 2.0?

Comment: @Rono `DefaultPolicy` still exists in ASP.NET Core 2.0 as you can see [in `AuthorizationOptions` on the `rel/2.0.0` tag](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationOptions.cs). Could you double check?

Comment: My bad, I was looking at AddAuthentication instead of AddAuthorization.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with this, might help :

```
    public class OnlyDebugModeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
#if DEBUG

        //Ok
#else
        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        return;
#endif

    }
}
```

and then apply it on controler

```
[OnlyDebugMode]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DebugController : ControllerBase
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

New attribute for your controllers:

`[AzureADAuthorize]`

AzureADAuthorize.cs:

```
public class AzureADAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public AzureADAuthorize() : base(AzureADPolicies.Name)
        {
        }

    }
```

AzureADPolicies.cs:

```
public static class AzureADPolicies
    {
        public static string Name => "AzureADAuthorizationRequired";

        public static void Build(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder)
            {
                if (StaticRepo.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EnableAuthorization") == true)
                {
                    var section = StaticRepo.Configuration.GetSection($"AzureAd:AuthorizedAdGroups");
                    var groups = section.Get<string[]>();
                    builder.RequireClaim("groups", groups);

                }
                else if (StaticRepo.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EnableAuthentication") == true)
                {
                    builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                }else
                {
                    builder
                    .RequireAssertion(_ => true)
                    .Build();
                }             
            }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
//Authentication & Authorization
            #region AUTHENTICATION / AUTHORICATION

            StaticRepo.Configuration = Configuration;


                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(
                        AzureADPolicies.Name, AzureADPolicies.Build);
                });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            #endregion
```

Appsettings.json:

```
 "EnableAuditLogging": false,
  "EnableAuthentication": true,
  "EnableAuthorization": false,
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "https://MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com/",
    "TenantId": "b6909603-e5a8-497d-8fdb-7f10240fdd10",
    "ClientId": "6d09a1bf-4678-4aee-b67c-2d6df68d5324",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    //Your Azure AD Security Group Object IDs that users needs to be member of to gain access
    "AuthorizedAdGroups": [
      "568bd325-283f-4909-9fcc-a493d19f98e8",
      "eee6d366-0f4d-4fca-9965-b2bc0770506d"
    ]
  }
```

(These are random guids)

Now you can conditional control if you want to have anonymous access, azure ad authentication,  authentication + group authorization. There are still some stuff you need to setup in your azure ad app manifest file to get it to work, but I think it's outside the scope here.