# asp.net MVC Action available only to X environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a more convenient way to make the action available only to X environment ?

For the time being, I can do something simple as this :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult MenualTransactionHandling()
    {
        if(env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Code
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            // Any other enviroment will not enter
            return Forbid();
        }
    }
```

I would like something like this :

```
[Development]
public IActionResult MenualTransactionHandling() { /*Code*/ return Ok(); }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41579022/11683 and links there there for how to define an authorization attribute based on the environment.

Comment: If its purely a debug action and doesn't need to be in any other builds, you could use also wrap it in a [#if block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) or mark it with a [conditionalattribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute). This would remove it entirely unless some compiler symbols are defined.

Comment: Thanks, both of you helped me alot!
Since it was for debugging purposes, I made a simple action filter with the #if DEBUG block for checking